# Unit Test Synchronous Code has a Race Condition?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, race-condition

I have uploaded some code on git hub that can be found here:
https://github.com/Shaunus87/SyncTest that includes my prototype code and my unit tests for it.

I essentially declare my synchronous code, hook up an event, call a method that will eventually call the event, and assert whether the event was called or not:

```
        bool called = false;

        var testBinsToVend = GetRoboBins();
        var vendHelper = new VendingHelper(null, testBinsToVend, VendType.Issue);

        vendHelper.Complete += delegate () {
            called = true;
        };

        vendHelper.DoVending();

        Assert.IsTrue(called);
```

All the code is synchronous (as far as I know), yet if I run the test it fails, if I debug through it, it passes...

I've tried a few things and it seems like either a) my code is secretly async and I have a race condition or b) when running the code it decides not to execute half of the events?

What the hell?

**Edit:**
I've also tried setting a manual reset event like below:

```
        bool called = false;
        var done = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        var testBinsToVend = GetRoboBins();
        var vendHelper = new VendingHelper(null, testBinsToVend, VendType.Issue);

        vendHelper.Complete += delegate () {
            called = true;
            done.Set();
        };

        vendHelper.DoVending();

        done.WaitOne();
        Assert.IsTrue(called);
        //was complete called?
        Assert.AreEqual(true, vendHelper.Bins.All(x => x.State != VendState.Pending));
```

but since it's one line of execution, when `done.WaitOne();` is hit the test never reaches the `Assert.IsTrue(called);` line.

Comment: I found references to `System.Threading.Timer` in there, you **sure** your code is synchronous? From where is that event fired? Inside [Timer_Tick](https://github.com/Shaunus87/SyncTest/blob/master/eVendVendingMachines/BaseVendingMachine.cs#L182) ? Place a breakpoint on that `called = true;` line and inspect the call stack, this will likely tell you everything you need to know during debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a problem in your business logic:

```
private CommCommand GetLastCommand(List<CommCommand> cmds, DateTime since) {
 return cmds.Where(x => x.DateTime > since)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

`DateTime.Now` only has a resolution of about 20ms or so by default. Which means that your message is received long before `DateTime > since` would be true. When you step through the code, the timing gets adjusted - the `Send` happens a lot longer after the original receive.

You can't rely on `DateTime.Now` for message ordering. It simply doesn't have enough accuracy. If you really think you can rely on the order of sends and receives for ordering (that is, the machine never replies before it gets prompted), replace it with a simple counter instead.

Comment: Yes!! I was just about to ask how you think I should order it then saw your edit pop up. Thank you so much I had no idea DateTime wasn't accurate for stuff like that. How did you actually discover the DateTimes was the problem? (I've been banging my head up a wall thinking it's a race condition >.< )

Comment: @Smithy Well, first I put a breakpoint in the Complete handler - so I'd now it really wasn't invoked. Then I made sure the test didn't end before it had a chance to run, just in cause there was really an asynchronous problem. Then I checked where the handler was *supposed* to be invoked, and traced which of those you expected to be raised. Then I checked the pre-conditions, and printed out whenever a message was sent (`Debug.WriteLine` is useful). Finally, I put a breakpoint in the WorkOnResponse for FET (the command last that worked properly), and saw `lastRecCmd` being null...

Comment: @Smithy ... while `receivedCommands` weren't empty and indeed contained the expected last response. Which made it clear that `GetLastCommand` is at fault - and when I saw the `DateTime` comparison, I didn't need to dig any further. Debugging is a bit of an art :D

Comment: Awww I did the same thing but just stupidly came to the conclusion there was some secret async + race condition on the test because I could step through it and it worked fine. Thanks again mate, much appreciated :)

Comment: @Smithy Jumping to conclusions is a big problem, yeah :D Then you spend hours investigating *the wrong problem*. It happens to me all the time, it's a common human bias (and I can't really say it's a bad idea in general - how often is the first idea you have the right one?). Just keep subdividing the problem, eliminating circumstances until you're left with the smallest piece of code that still exhibits the problem. This is easier said than done, of course... :)